# En laravel como mandar e invocar mas datos con Markdowns Mail

Tags: php, laravel, markdown

tengo esta duda de como enviar varios datos en un `array` y que al invocar estos datos en la plantilla que se enviara pueda declarlos en diferentes secciones, esto es lo que tengo

este es mi Mailable

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class EncuestaSolvex extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
        ->from('no-replysolvesintel@encuesta.com')
        ->subject('Resultados de Encuesta')
        ->markdown('emails.encuesta')
        ->with(['data', $this->data]);
    }
}
```

Esta es la parte del controlador

```
public function email(Request $request)
    {
        $email=DB::table('usuario')
        ->where('id_usu', '=', $request->get('id'))
        ->get(); 
        $nombre=DB::table('usuario')
        ->where('id_usu', '=', $request->get('id'))
        ->get(); 
        $usuario = Usuario::findOrFail($email[0]->id_usu);


        $data = array('email' => $usuario->email,'nombre' => $usuario->nombre);

    Mail::to($usuario->email)->send(new EncuestaSolvex($data));
        return "success";
    }
```

y esta es la plantilla que se envia por email

```
@component('mail::message')
# Introduction

The body of your message.
@foreach ($data as $data)
<ul>
    Nombre: {{ $data }}
    </ul>
@endforeach
{{-- Nomre: {{ $data }}
 --}}
@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
Button Text
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Cuando quiero tomar solo un dato digase nombre o email, no me deja, o mas bien no se como hacerlo, no puedo poner `$data-nombre` porque me marca que intento invocar un no objeto, entonces de que manera podria?

Comment: Por qué no pasar directamente el objeto `$usuario` `al mail`,  en lugar de crear un nuevo `array` y realizar el `cast` a Object ? , es decir `Mail::to($usuario->email)->send(new EncuestaSolvex($usuario))`

Comment: necesito buscar el `id` del usuario que realizo el test,  lo hago por separado del una authenicacion de usuario, al final del test manda  ese `id` para que lo pueda comparar y que mande su nombre y su email, y si te das cuenta lo tengo asi como tu indicas, solo que en el `array` paso los datos que mostrare en el cuerpo del email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada si vas a recorrer un arreglo intenta no asignarle al valor o a la clave de cada iteración el mismo nombre de variable que el arreglo que estas recorriendo.

```
foreach($data as $data)  //Esto esta mal

foreach($data as $item)  //Esto esta bien
```

Ahora si pasas a la vista un `arreglo` de esta forma:

```
$data = array('email' => $usuario->email,'nombre' => $usuario->nombre);
```

Puedes acceder a el en la `vista` de esta manera:

```
Nombre: {{ $data['nombre'] }}
Correo: {{ $data['email'] }}
```

Si quieres acceder a los indices como si fuera un objeto debes pasar el arreglo como una instancia de `stdObject`, es decir en tu `controladora` deberias reemplazar

**ESTO**:

```
$data = array('email' => $usuario->email,'nombre' => $usuario->nombre);
```

**POR:**

```
$data = (object) array('email' => $usuario->email,'nombre' => $usuario->nombre);
```

Y ya en tu `plantilla` puedes mostrarlo de esta manera:

```
Nombre: {{ $data->nombre }}
Correo: {{ $data->email }}
```

Si no quieres mostrar cada elemento por separado y reducirlo en una sola línea puedes usar un ciclo `foreach` y quedaria:

```
{% foreach($data as $key => $item) %}
    {{ ucfirst($key) }}: {{ $item }}
{% endforeach %}
```

De esta manera mostrarias algo como

```
Nombre: nombre1
Correo: correo@algo.com
```

Comment: O podría pasar directamente el objeto que retorna `findOrFail` al mail ;)

Comment: Jajjaja estas en lo cierto :-P